# Unable to write data into blockchain - Ganache

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache

I've this contract and web3js html GUI that's interacting with it. The contract is deployed in ganache at localhost 8545 and unable to write data into blockchain.

SimpleStorage.sol -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;


contract SimpleStorage {   uint myVariable;   string myName;
     //mapping (myName => address) name;

  function set(uint x) public {
    myVariable = x;   }

  function get() constant public returns (uint) {
    return myVariable;   }
     function setName(string name) constant public  {
    myName = name;   }
     function getName() constant public returns (string) {
    return myName;   }    }
```

SimpleStorage.html -

```
<!doctype><html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="bignumber.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="web3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545")); 
var abi =[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0xfe9052ae2dbc665deb92a735c913e73510c50cdc');
console.log("Writing to block " + myContractInstance.set(1)); // This is what is not working. I know I'm doing something wrong here but couldn't figure out.
console.log("Getting data " + myContractInstance.get()); //This returns result 
document.getElementById("connectContractAdress").innerHTML = "Connected to Contract. Contract Owner is "+ myContractInstance.get();
</script></head><body><div id="connectContractAdress"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Please add the error output, so that we can understand the problem better

Comment: Uncaught Error: invalid address -- that's in chrome console.

Comment: you probably need to add a from attribute to your `myContractInstance.set(1,{from:0x....})`
or maybe you are wrong about your contract address, the one you are adding statically there.

Comment: Yeh.. And also I need to unlock the account and use eth.sendTransaction() right? So, it goes something like 1. Unlock account 2. contract.GetFunction("set").sendTransaction(coinbase, etc.,.,).. Do you have any documentation on it?

Comment: I don't think you need to unlockAccount since ganache gives you 10 fully unlocked and funded accounts, so when sending any transaction you only need to use `web3.eth.accounts[0] or 1`. you won't change anything in your code, all you need to to is add the from attribute like i mentioned earlier like this : 
`myContractInstance.set(1,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:300000})`

Comment: Yes, - thank you so much @Med Mansour.. It worked.. Wait.. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Med Mansour for guiding. Here is the code to call 'set' method in contract.

```
function setData() { 
    var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0xfe9052ae2dbc665deb92a735c913e73510c50cdc');

    var unlockAccount = web3.personal.unlockAccount('0xfc2AcBF73016Fb3449837b4748a87e90E82c45C7','',300);
    strUnlockAccount = (unlockAccount == null )? "NULL": unlockAccount.toString();
    document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText = "Account unlock status = "+strUnlockAccount;

    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputNumber").value);
    //console.log("Number " , number);
    var txHash = myContractInstance.set(number,{from:'0xfc2AcBF73016Fb3449837b4748a87e90E82c45C7', gas:'6721975', gasPrice:'0'});
    document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText = document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText + "\nTransaction has after setting value to " + number + "  = " + txHash;

    var blockNumber = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').number;
    //web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(req,res) { blockNumber = res ; } );
    console.log("Block #" + blockNumber);
    document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText = document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText + "\nCurrent Block Number = "+ blockNumber;

    document.getElementById("blockHashDetails").innerText = JSON.stringify(web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.getBlock('latest').number));

    var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0xfe9052ae2dbc665deb92a735c913e73510c50cdc');
    document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText = document.getElementById("setdatavalue").innerText + "\nGetting data value after change= " + myContractInstance.get();
}
```